# HTML Managing large drop down menus

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 10 dropdown menus on a page, each dropdown menu has about 30 items.

This takes up a ton of lines of code, and even impedes page loading time by a small amount.

A. Is there a way to simplify the amount of code that contains these dropdown menus?

B. Is there a way to improve this pages performance?

Comment: the best way will be to create a `plugin` and manage whole `dropdown menu` through it...

Comment: @Sally any links you could refer me to?

Comment: Combine the 10 menus into a single menu for A and B. Are each of the menus its own jQuery plugin or are you simply using jQuery for the element and event tools?

Comment: sure thing, this is pretty simple one but I guess you can extend it according to your needs: http://www.benlor.com.au/scripts/dropmenu.js
implemented here: http://www.benlor.com.au/

Comment: `Knockout.js` is useful for this sort of stuff as well..

Answer (score 1):

You can check this cool plugin for dropdown menu, it may help you construct your code better,
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

If you really have a **huge** menu, you may consider make your menu items into a javascript Array or Object, the use javascript function to render the menu rather than plain HTML code to save page size.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to exchange the select fields with autocomplete input fields fed by an ajax call?

There are some advantages to this approach:

1. Less HTML code
2. Faster page load
3. User friendly

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that having an ajax call request the each menu would be speedier than raw html? If so, this will be the route I take.

Answer (score 0):

If each one of the dropdown menus has a certain type of data so lets say animals or trees e.t.c you could create a database and dynamically pull them into a dropdown menu. it would be some what quicker than than trying to manually load them all at one. 
Using this method would simplify the process a lot and also make it more dynamic to add new options if u like i can write you up some basic code to get you started??